# Using the "condition ? :" construct

Tags: bash

I am using the following construct and cannot understand why it produces a syntax error.

```
(( r == 1 )) ? return 0 : return 1
```

What is the construct `condition ? :` called exactly?

Comment: It's usually called [the ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Whatever makes you think you can use it in bash directly like this?

Comment: Did not find instances of its use, so I started playing around.

Answer (score 1):

In bash , syntax is like below:

```
$ echo $((0 ? 5 : 6 ))
6
$ echo $((1 ? 5 : 6 ))
5
```

Comment: So the construct is simply for numeric assignment `a=$(( r==1 ? 5 : 8 ))` rather than to invoke general commands as can be done by the `if`, `case`, or `while` conditional statements.

Comment: @Fatipati Shell syntax is extremely context-dependent, and the ternary operator is no exception. It's only available in arithmetic contexts, like in `(( ))`, `$(( ))`, the index of a (non-associative) array, or a few other places.